# Elegant C++ Code: How to write more efficient code using while loops and conditional statements

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

Would you be able to give me some suggestions for how I could simplify my code?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std; 



int main() {

    string current_users[5];
    string new_users[5], new_user;
    ifstream read;


    read.open("current.txt");

    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
        read >> current_users[index];

    }

    read.close();


    cout << "Enter a username: ";
    cin >> new_user;


    char user_choice;
    int index = 0, new_index = 0;
    while (index <= 5) {


        if (new_user == current_users[index]) {
            cout << "That username already exists."
                << " Enter a different username: ";

            cin >> new_user;
            index = 0;
            continue;
        }


        if (index < 5)
            index++;


        else {
            new_users[new_index] = new_user;
            cout << "\nWelcome " << new_user << endl;
            new_index++;


             if (new_index < 5) {
               cout << "Would you like to register another user?:" 
                            <<"'Y' for yes or 'N' for no";
                cin >> user_choice;
            }


            if (user_choice == 'Y' || user_choice == 'y') {
                cout << "\nEnter a new username: ";
                cin >> new_user;
                index = 0;
            }

            else
              break;

        }

    }//end of while 

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

This program asks a user to enter a username and checks if that username already exists. If it exists, it prompts the user to use a different username, also checking if that username already exists. If the username is unique the program welcomes the new user and asks if the user wants to register another new user (weird, but I wanted to try it). If the user wants to add another user to the "website" per say then the program runs again, checking for redundancy. I limited this program to 5 possible usernames to check and add for ease of testing. There's no errors.

The code is just chunky. I came up with this problem. I'm not in school. Can't afford it and wasn't admitted to any school where I applied. Any suggestions for online schools that offer degrees in computer science?

Comment: A `std::vector` could help.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ `StackOverflow` is more about broken code that you want fixed. `CodeReview` is about working code you want improved.

Comment: Semi-related: Do not confuse short and complex with good code. Quite often short and stupid is the right way to go. Short because code that doesn't exist has no bugs and stupid because it's easy to read, debug, and maintain. One of the keys to short is leveraging other people's code, especially the Standard Library. Only complicate things when stupid doesn't meet the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what you have is good. I'd wrap everything into a function and use `std::find` from the standard library in order to find duplicates.

```c++
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void GetUsers( std::string (&new_users)[N], std::string const (&current_users)[M] ) {
  int idx = 0;
  while (idx < 5) {
    std::cout << "Enter a username: ";
    std::string user; std::cin >> user;
    if (std::find(current_users.begin(), current_users.end(), user) != current_users.end()) {
      std::cout << "That username already exists.\n";
      continue;
    } else {
      new_users[idx++] = user;
      if (idx < 5) {
        std::cout << "Would you like to register another user? [Y/n]: ";
        if (std::tolower(std::cin.get()) == 'y') {
          continue;
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

### Array of Structures not parallel arrays

Use a `std::vector` of structures and not parallel arrays:

```
struct Record
{
    std::string  new_user;
    std::string  current_user;
};
std::vector<Record> database;
```

Processors that use a data cache like to have their elements close together.  Here, `new_user[0]` would be next to `current_user[0]` in the cache.

With your parallel arrays, `new_users[0]` is next to `current_user[4]`; so the processor has to go past 4 elements to get to the first `new_users` element.

### Loop Unrolling

You could eliminate the `for` loop for reading in your values:

```
read >> current_users[0];
read >> current_users[1];
read >> current_users[2];
read >> current_users[3];
read >> current_users[4];
```

This eliminates the overhead associated with a `for` loop.

### Convert to all Lower or all Upper case before comparing

You can reduce the number of comparisons by converting to uppercase or lowercase before comparing:

```
if (std::toupper(user_choice) == 'Y')
```

Comment: Avoid manually loop unrolling. Loop is more readable, avoid copy/paste of the code. Compiler would probably unroll the loop (if better) anyway.

Comment: Loops may be more readable, but the OP asked for efficiency.  Manually unrolling a loop does not depend on compiler settings.

Comment: Compiler can also do the reverse (creating a loop) anyway. so you always depend of compiler (settings).